# selecting only desired firleds from query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a many to many relation between `sizes` and `toppings` and and have a thrird table which contains extra fields the table is named `toppings_sizes`

Now I want to select only one field from `toppings_sizes`, at the moment I have a query which delivers all available field in all 3 tables.

```
$rs = $this->Toppings
     ->find()
     ->contain(['Sizes'])
     ->where(['category_id' => $categoryId]);

debug( json_encode($rs, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

I this can I need only 2 fields `Sizes.name` and `ToppingsSizes.price`

Answer (score 0):

One way is by adding `->select` to specify fields:

```
$rs = $this->Toppings
    ->find()
    ->select(['Sizes.name', 'ToppingsSizes.price'])
    ->contain(['Sizes'])
    ->where(['category_id' => $categoryId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = $this->Toppings
    ->find()
    ->contain([
            'Sizes' => function ($q) {
               return $q
                    ->select(['name']);

            },
            'ToppingsSizes' => function ($q) {
               return $q
                    ->select(['price']);
            }
        ]);
    ->where(['category_id' => $categoryId]);
```

By Using this code you can get desired fields from table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Relationship model names into `contain()` method array which model entity you need in result data.

```
$rs = $this->Toppings
    ->find()
    ->select(['Sizes.name', 'ToppingsSizes.price'])
    ->contain(['Sizes','ToppingsSizes'])
    ->where(['Toppings.category_id' => $categoryId]);
```